# Comparing multiple classifiers over a single dataset

Tags: classification, model-selection, model-comparison, multivariate-analysis

Im doing a comparison between 4 classifiers : A linear SVM, a random forest classifier, a multivariate gaussian and a neural network, for a dataset with 50 features and 10000 examples, the observations belong to 2 classes.

What is the best way to compare them ? I mean, should I use F-score, Precision/Recall or maybe logloss to see which one performs better on the test subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best score function is the one that models what you want your models to do. *You* need to define what it means for one model to be better than another. This should be defined before you start modeling based on the problem you are trying to solve in the first place.

Some medical examples of why we cannot answer the question for you:

1. Screening tests: high recall because you don't want to miss potentially sick patients.
2. Diagnostic tests: high precision because you don't want to call a healthy patient sick (and potentially inducing surgery or what not).

If you have no specific goals but want to compare models over their entire operating range you can use area under the [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve.

Comment: The problem is that I dont have enough computational power and time to do such a comparison of the classifiers through the ROC curve, and my classes are skewed

Comment: Computing ROC curves is not a computationally heavy task. Whatever performance measure you intend to use will require you to make predictions with all classifiers. In ROC analysis you just use the decision values instead of labels. ROC analysis is still useful when your classes are skewed, but working with area under the [Precision-Recall curve](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/295592/1/d.) may be better.